# Maven failsafe. How to execute only the suite file and not standalone tests?

Tags: java, maven, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have a submodule that run integration tests for the whole project, which have several modules. This is the integration tests submodule pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.sample.server</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-test</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sample.server.modules</groupId>
    <artifactId>integration_test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>integration_test</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sample.server.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <suiteXmlFiles>
                                <suiteXmlFile>${project.basedir}/testng/api.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                            </suiteXmlFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

            </plugin>
</project>
```

When I execute mvn install or verify then all the standalone tests run and after that the xml suite run too.

I only want to run the suite file, I need to do it this way because some test fails outside of the suite. 
I tried with the exclude option but failsafe is ignoring that option.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the pom.xml to

```
 <configuration>

 <excludes>
            <exclude>**/TestCircle.java</exclude>
            <exclude>**/TestSquare.java</exclude>
          </excludes>
 <suiteXmlFiles>
                                <suiteXmlFile>${project.basedir}/testng/api.xml</suiteXmlFile>
 </suiteXmlFiles>
</configuration>
```

where the exclusions are the tests you don't want to run.

Comment: But that skip the xml suite too

Comment: No, no, you hasn't understood what is my problem. I don't want to skip or exclude the tests, I want to execute those test, but from the xml file. Right now failsafe is executing the tests standalone and the xml file, I just want to execute the xml file.

Comment: I found the problem. Was the parent pom who was executing the tests standalone. So, the solution was skip tests at parent level and re-enable it in the submodule. I valid your answer because you show me the way